# Is "thank you to..." Correct

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I often read "thank you to people who..." And "thank you to everyone..." On facebook.

I think it should be "thanks to people..." And thanks to everyone".

What do you think?

Comment: That was supposed to be in a pair or quotes. " "thank you" to people who... "

Comment: "Thanks to people" puts them in the third person. "Thank you to people" puts them in the second person: "To those people, (I address you and say) thank you (directly to you)."

Comment: Possibly ellipsis for '[I'd like to say] "thank you" to [the] people...'

Answer (score 4):

As [Kris](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/14666/kris) points out, there are missing speech marks. It should be:

> 'Thank you' to everyone...

which is possibly a shortened form of:

> [I'd like to say] 'thank you' to everyone...
>
> [I'd like to say] 'Thank you' to [the] people...

Because of the [register](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/%7Eharoldfs/messeas/regrep/node2.html) of an informal Facebook post, this form is acceptable usage.